# stuck ubuntu 18.04 upgrade from ubuntu 16.04, at installing the updates

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, system-installation, upgrade

The upgrade got stuck at installing snap gnome characters, I don't know what to do please help me to resolve this issue without causing any damage to the system or its data.
Please refer to the image to get a better idea of the problem.
[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dOs5.png)

Comment: When you click on “Terminal”, do you see an error message or interaction displayed near the bottom?

Comment: I tried to click on the "Terminal", but it is not opening up or responding as if the whole thing is stuck or frozen.

Comment: Sounds like the machine has frozen. If you have a second computer, you *might* be able to SSH into it to see whether the machine has locked up completely, but only if you have configured the system to allow that. Otherwise, a hard reboot will be required.

Comment: System is working fine, just this distribution upgrader has stopped working. I'm little afraid that if I do the hard reboot, it might lead to some problems.

Comment: If the system is still responsive except for this window, then it would be a good idea to check the logs. From a terminal, try `sudo tail -f /var/log/apt/term.log`. This will show the last few lines from the apt log. If there are errors, then share them back here so that someone can help out 

Comment: I have taken the screenshot of the result, from running the above command, here's the link [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1drLOR1ksr2QZHCIwFJnK_Ashz7fXXZP1/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Well this is certainly a challenge. There are some options, but there is a risk of the system going into emergency mode on the next reboot depending on the reason for the failure. If you `sudo dpkg --configure -a` do you get an error?

Comment: After running the command I got this :--
dpkg: error: dpkg frontend is locked by another process

Comment: Yeah, I figured you might. You're going to need to make a decision, now. If the update has completely stopped, you will need to kill the process. Once the process is gone, then you can try `sudo dpkg --configure -a` again. If that doesn't work, then you'll need to do this: `sudo apt autoclean` ⇢ `sudo apt clean` ⇢ `sudo apt update` ⇢ `sudo apt dist-upgrade`. *Hopefully* this will give you a working 18.04 installation.

Comment: I ran the command `sudo lsof /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend` and got this [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aYOedf9yKr-elC7yErdVoA42m5Qq489o/view?usp=sharing). So should I kill this process or not?